# Array: identifier "array" is undefined

Tags: c++, arrays

Every time I run this code in Visual Studio 2015 it shows the error identifier "treasureLocation" is undefined... what am I doing wrong?

```
int main()
{
int gridSize [2];
int gridX = 0;
int gridY = 0;
int treasureLoaction[2];
int end;


std :: cout << "what size grid would you like to play on?" << std :: endl;

std :: cin >> gridSize [1];
std :: cin >> gridSize [2];

treasureLocation[1] = rand() % gridSize[1] + 1;
treasureLocation[2] = rand() % gridSize[2] + 1;

while (gridY < gridSize[2]) {
    gridY++;
    while (gridX < gridSize[1]) {
        std::cout << "* ";
        gridX++;
    } 
    std::cout << "" << std::endl;
    gridX = 0;
};

std::cout << treasureLoaction;
std::cin >> end;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `std::cout << treasureLoaction;` You can't do that with an array. Although you spelled it wrong also.

Comment: `treasureLoaction != treasureLocation`, closing as a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo

```
int treasureLoaction[2];
            ^^^^^^^^
```

Take into account that if an array has `n` elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, n-1]`

And this statement

```
std::cout << treasureLoaction;
```

does not outputs the elements of the array as you might think.

You could do it in a loop as for example

```
for ( int x : treasureLocation ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating through the array to print its contents like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < your array length; i++) cout << array[i];
```

unless you are trying to print the address, and it also looks like you have a spelling error in treasureLoaction.